# oracle : Writing an Oracle FileSize function

Tags: arrays, oracle, select, package

I'm writing an Oracle packaged function that returns size of file to formatted with unit (octet, Ko, Mo, Go...).
Here is the code (package body) :

```
create or replace package body Tools is

    TYPE SizeName IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(2);
    C_SizeName SizeName := SizeName('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');

    function fileSize(pSize in number) return varchar2 is
        OneKO constant number := 1024;
        val varchar2(10);
    begin
        select round(pSize / power(OneKO, idx), 3) || ' ' || C_SizeName(idx)
          into val
          from dual
         cross apply (select floor(log(OneKO, pSize)) idx
                        from dual);
        return val;
    end fileSize;

end Tools;
```

Unfortunately, I get ORA-00904 on C_SizeName(idx) is select.
I've tried to use C_SizeName as a table in from clause :

```
        select round(pSize / power(OneKO, idx), 3) || ' ' || sn.column_value
          into val
          from dual
             , table(C_SizeName) sn
         cross apply (select floor(log(OneKO, pSize)) idx
                        from dual)
         where sn.column_index = idx ;
        return val;
```

but don't know how to use it this way (where clause on sn)...
... and get ORA-22905 with line ", table(C_SizeName) sn"...

Any help will be cool
Thanks.
Alain

Comment: You would need to create the type as a database object, e.g. `create or replace type sizename is ...`

Comment: @Boneist Ok, but how should I filter my table(C_SizeName) array ? I guess there is a pseudo column like the "column_value" but can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use it in SQL - do it all in PL/SQL.

**Package Specification**:

```sql
create or replace package Tools is
    function fileSize(pSize in number) return varchar2;
end Tools;
/
```

**Package Body**:

```sql
create or replace package body Tools is
  TYPE SizeName IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(2);
  C_SizeName SizeName := SizeName('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');

  function fileSize(pSize in number) return varchar2
  is
    OneKO CONSTANT NUMBER(4,0) := 1024;
    idx   CONSTANT NUMBER(1,0) := FLOOR( LOG( OneKO, pSize ) );
    units CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2) := C_SizeName( idx + 1 );
  begin
    RETURN round(pSize / power(OneKO, idx), 3) || units;
  end fileSize;
end Tools;
/
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT Tools.fileSize( 1024 ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | TOOLS.FILESIZE(1024) |
> | :------------------- |
> | 1KB                  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be4c7fb299990a8665ec4ea5d9874b66)*

Comment: Fine ! I'm such a fool ! The is actually no need to use SQL !!! Thanks @mt0

Comment: For those who would be interested by this program, don't forget to test if parameter pSize is less or equal 0 (because of log function). That will change a lot the code :-)

Comment: You'll add a context switch in if you use SQL (which may harm performance) and you'll need to declare the `VARRAY` in an SQL context (rather than a PL/SQL context) and will be fighting the SQL syntax to get the correct index of the `VARRAY` but it is possible in SQL [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9cde27c01a68c9fdae7d97464843d5d0)